# jQueryUI Dialog window won't close on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-ui, ios-simulator, jquery-ui-dialog

We are using jQueryUI dialog windows on our site as containers for pop-up videos. These work great with the exception that the close "x" does not work on the iPad. I have no idea why this would be or how to go about debugging it.

Any ideas? Do I need to post some kind of code?

Comment: Trying calling $("#popup").dialog("close") on your dialog through javascript. If that works, you have a touch problem. If not, it's a javascript problem.

Comment: OK. But how would I go about doing that? It's not as if I have a developer console on the iPad..

Comment: And then download Weinre so that you can debug on your iPad: http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/